# XCode 6.0.1 Crashed on Start

Tags: xcode, xcode6.0.1

Please help me with new xcode 6.0.1 it crashes every time i open xcode. When i tried to open organiser and devices window it also crashed. Tried reinstalling but no help.
Here is what i found in Crash Report. Please help

```
Process:         Xcode [50722]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 712682811
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [249]
Responsible:     Xcode [50722]
User ID:         501


Date/Time:       2014-09-24 21:36:47.767 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FE59939D-77EB-E1A2-5DEF-E4AE4F6B7307


Sleep/Wake UUID: FD8DA654-A406-42D0-9D33-095BC63DA215


Crashed Thread:  19


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000


Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6245/Xcode3Core/Le gacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetB uildContext.mm:1875
Details:  filePath='/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/KegVision-ct wyoosnwujkvtduxpfhsixymdkm/Build/Intermediates/KegVision.build/Debug-iphonesimul ator/KegVision.build/KegVision-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap'
Object:   <PBXTargetBuildContext: 0x7f96d5e123f0>
Method:   -defineFileContents:forAuxiliaryFileAtPath:withPosixPermissions:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f96d6e0ac20>{name = (null), num = 9}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:

      0  0x000000010bdfff0a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageForm at:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
      1  0x000000010abbdbaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2  0x000000010abbde9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3  0x00000001151ddf0a -[PBXTargetBuildContext defineFileContents:forAuxiliaryFileAtPath:withPosixPermissions:] (in DevToolsCore)
      4  0x00000001151de691 -[PBXTargetBuildContext defineFileContents:forAuxiliaryFileAtPath:] (in DevToolsCore)
      5  0x00000001152dc15e -[XCDependencyGraphCreationContext defineFileContents:forAuxiliaryFileAtPath:] (in DevToolsCore)
      6  0x00000001152b796e -[XCToolSpecificationHeadermapGenerator createCommandsforInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
      7  0x00000001151dad74 -[PBXTargetBuildContext invokeTask:forInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:optionTable:] (in DevToolsCore)
      8  0x00000001152dc4bd -[XCDependencyGraphCreationContext invokeTask:forInputs:withMacroExpansionScope:optionTable:] (in DevToolsCore)
      9  0x000000011532eee5 -[XCCommandLineToolInvocation createDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
    10  0x00000001151e249a -[PBXTargetBuildContext generateHeadermapFilesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
```

Comment: Did you try installing it directly from the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart Mac OS, open Xcode again. if it can not resolve your problem try to use [App Cleaner](http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac)  to completely uninstall Xcode. Try reinstalling again.

Comment: Tried directly installing from App Store, its updated from 5 to 6 , then i uninstalled it, tried to open again same error.

Comment: tried restarting Mac OS,no help.now preforming clean installation.